# How to keep search input value after route change? Angular

Tags: angular, search, routes

I have a basic app with route setup for 2 components: HomeComponent and SearchComponent. 
- The SearchComponent is displayed in the HomeComponent.
- Inside the SearchComponent there a simple search form with 1 input and 1 submit button.

I want to understand is how to keep the search input value after the query is submitted and the route changes to /search?q=whatever

Thanks

[image: HomeComponent]
[image: SearchComponent]
[image: app-routing]
[image: Homepage]
[image: Search Route - After Submit]
[image: Routing Module]

Comment: In your router configuration try a `pathMatch: full` for the default route.

Answer (score 0):

How are you using Router and your routes without the router-outlet, instead nesting one component in another? The only way routes and [Router](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt5) work - is with the router outlet, you don't use any component selectors - you define routes exactly for that. Of course, without all that you can't pass any route params or use any of provided features.

[Forms](https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview) in Angular also work another way - there are special directives and data-binding to prevent the default behaviour (because Angular projects are single page apps, so after compiling you have only one index.html, which Angular manipulates).

Comment: I've added the app-routing.module.ts screenshot to the post.
After digging a bit deeper. I think my issue might be the page reload, as the /search is reloaded after the form is submitted.

Any idea how to submit a form without reloading the route?

Comment: it's not enough to add the routing module. as I wrote, this is absolutely useless without adding the router-outlet tag in your html

Comment: Hey Dasha. The router-outlet tag is of course added as well in the main app.component.ts. Otherwise the routes wouldn't work at all. Now, as I said the routes work perfectly, my issue is with the form input value="THIS" after the routes change..

Comment: 1) you can use Angular Reactive Forms, using (ngSubmit) listener, the form will not be reset if you don't reset it with the .reset() method; 2) but therefore, I assume from screenshots, that you have 2 instances of search component: the one is in the tag < app-search > (why??), the second is provided by router, so these are 2 different forms... do you use RouterParams for passing "?q=whatever" ? if yes - you can get from ActivatedRoute.snapshot.params...